# Already Installed package on cmd then how it work on pycharm?

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm

> I want to install one package on cmd then it also work on pycharm. No need to download or install it from pycharm. How it is possible? Please help me. I already installed that package on cmd.

Comment: setup your pycharm project with the good python interpreter

Comment: Is there any option for not to install same packages everytime? I mean, I install one package one time then no need to install anymore. Likely i just write 'import numpy as np' and it work.@azro

Comment: A package is not ever installed for only cmd or only for pycharm, it's installed _for a specific python interpreter_ (or virtualenv, or so forth). Your job is to make sure cmd and pycharm both use the same interpreter. Right now, the question doesn't have enough details for us to know why/how your two environments don't _already_ share the same interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

#### Adding a Path

Go into File > Settings > Project Settings > Project Interpreter.

Then press configure interpreter, and navigate to the "Paths" tab.

pycharm path tab

Press the + button in the Paths area. You can put the path to the module you'd like it to recognize.

But I don't know the path..
Open the python interpreter where you can import the module.

```
>> import package_name
>> package_name.__file__

"path/to/package_name"
```

Most commonly you'll have a folder structure like this:

```
foobarbaz/
  Package_name/
    __init__.py
    other_file.py
```

You want to add foobarbaz to the path here.

Comment: Brother i already download package on cmd. With your method I have to download it again. Have you any other solution to you of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:

1. Initial installation of Python, **Add Python to Path** . was checked.
2. Initial installation of PyCharm.
3. A package is installed using command line `pip install package`.

Result:

1. Package is installed in the default installation of Python.

Next:

1. Start a new PyCharm project.
2. Select File menu |Settings
3. Check the Base interpreter, it will likely be the python.exe file in the default Python installation. If not, locate the python.exe file and select it.
4. **Check Inherit global-site packages.**
5. Click Create Button

Result: The project will be created with installed packages.